# How to pass parameters to translations

Tags: typescript, vue.js, internationalization, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm using vuejs 3 with TS.

I created the translation files in TS like this:

index.ts:

```
export default {
 'example': 'example',
}
```

In order then to use it in this way:

```
{{ $t('example') }}
```

Now I would like to pass a parameter to the translation, like, for example:

index.ts:

```
export default {
 'hi_man': 'Hi {name}',    //where the name is the parameter
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you should consider reading the documentation: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#named-formatting

```html
<p>{{ $t('hi_man', { name: 'Monkey' }) }}</p>
```

Comment: Yes, actually I read it and I noticed that I made a mistake in my code. I simply had a misspelling. Thanks a lot!